# Suma de Inputs con resultado en un input

Tags: html, jquery

estoy usando este código para ir sumando los valores que se escriban en los inputs e ir sumando en un resultado.

```js
function sumar() {

  var total = 0;

  $(".monto").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
```

Quiero saber como haría para que el resultado me lo coloque en un input type=text y que sea su value y no en un span, es que necesito enviar el resultado a un PHP para luego a una BD.

*Gracias!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir un `input` de tipo `hidden` para que esté oculto y no te dañe los posibles estilos que estés usando, y luego le asignas el valor correspondiente usando `.value`

```js
function sumar() {

  var total = 0;

  $(".monto").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
  document.getElementById('spTotal_input').value = total;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
<input type="hidden" name="spTotal_input" id="spTotal_input">
```